# Is there a measurable function $f$ such that $ \frac{1}{1-\varepsilon} f((1-\varepsilon)t) = 1_{\mathbb{Q}(t)},$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Is there a measurable function defined over $[0,1]$ denoted by $f$ satisfying the following:

$$ \frac{1}{1-\varepsilon} f((1-\varepsilon)t) = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(t)
,$$
for all $t\in [0,1]$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$ (small) ?

In other words, is there a function such that after a perturbation to the input $t$ and the function $f$ I can find the indicator function of the set $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: HI Brian, please check that you agree with the formatting change I just made

Comment: If so, please make the same change to the title

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the equation for $f(t)$, so
$$
f(t) = (1-\epsilon) 1_{\mathbb Q}(\frac t{1-\epsilon})
$$
is measurable and satisfies your equation.